# C library problems installing

Tags: c

I am a beginner C programmer, and recently I have run into a problem that I was unable to solve.

I am struggling to install and use a C library. The message error is:

[image]

My OS is Mac OS X and im try install the file with ".command" format.

**Can someone help me install this library?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `apt-get` is not a command in macOS.  You need to get the source code for the CS50 class from the GitHub repository and install it 'manually'.  You could try one of the alternative sources of pre-built software for Macs (e.g. Brew), but I'm not sure the library will be available from them.

Answer (score 0):

More than help installing the library, you need help in understanding what's going on.

Someone gave you a command to run and you ran it, but they were assuming that you were using a different OS, like Ubuntu.

The first message "apt-get not found" is because you're running MacOS, which doesn't have an "apt-get" command.

The second error is because you also don't have wget.

The rest of the messages indicate a poorly written script file, since it blew up twice and still went on to truncate files and do other things.

While you're not going to be able to install apt-get, you might be able to find a compatible version of wget. If not, you can download whatever it was trying to get using your browser, since wget is typically used to automate web HTTP/HTTPS requests.

Without seeing the file, I don't know what the rest if the script was trying to do, but if you read it you should be able to figure out what it was doing, and do it manually.

An easier way to do all this is to [install Virtualbox on your mac](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and run a copy of Ubuntu inside a virtual machine. Then you can run your class assignments without needing to rewrite them all.